# How to append a binary tree to another

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, tree

i am coding a function which should append a binary tree replacing a node of another tree. I am passing to the function the root of the two trees and the identifier of the node i want to replace, but i am not sure how to swap the address of the pointer which points to the node that i want to remove and set it to point to the root of the tree i want to append.

```
void Tree::appendTree(TreeNode *ptrMod, TreeNode *ptrApp, string 
type_node) {
    if (ptrMod == nullptr) {
        return;
    }
    if (ptrMod->getType() == type_node) {
        delete(ptrMod);
        ptrMod=ptrApp;
    } else {
        appendTree(*(ptrMod->getLeftAddress()),ptrApp,type_node);
        appendTree(*(ptrMod->getRightAddress()),ptrApp,type_node);
    }
}
```

ptrMod points to the node i am inspecting to check if it the node i want to replace.
ptrApp is the root of the tree i want to append.

Comment: Do you have a function that adds a node to the tree?  If you do, then why not traverse the source tree, and for each node, just add it to the destination tree and take advantage of code reuse?

Comment: How do you replace a node with a tree? What happens to the nodes children, where do they end up? It makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few changes needed: 1. Add a return value so you know if the swap was successful. 2. free memory recursively on the sub-tree deleted.

```
bool Tree::appendTree(TreeNode* & ptrMod, TreeNode* & ptrApp, string 
type_node) {
    if(ptrMod==nullptr)
    {
        return false; // did not swap
    }
    if(ptrMod->getType() == type_node){
        delete(ptrMod); // I hope you overloaded the delete operator to correctly delete all nodes of the tree
        ptrMod=ptrApp;
        return true; // swapped correctl;
        }
        else
        {
            if (appendTree(*(ptrMod->getLeftAddress()),ptrApp,type_node))
                return true;
            else return appendTree(*(ptrMod->getRightAddress()),ptrApp,type_node);
        }
}
```

Comment: How does this work? `ptrMod=ptrApp;` does nothing since `ptrMod` is a local variable.